# Ndiswrapper problems

Tags: 12.04, internet, ndiswrapper

I just got a fresh install of 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 and I had no internet.

I got `ndiswrapper` (just ndiswrapper, not utils or anything), I downloaded the drivers for my adapter (050d:6050) from the Belkin support website, and installed them. I installed the Vista drivers, did all the `iwconfig`, `modprobe`ing, etc... And I got nothing. I saw a thread telling about blacklisting rt2500usb and similar items, and still, nothing. So I went to install the Xperia drivers, did the same, and still nothing. `iwconfig` was empty both times.

Please help me, I don't know how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0):

[On Sourceforge wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Belkin_F6D6050nt), they directed me [to this link](http://www.belkin.com/au/support-article?rnId=3213). I'd recommend using the XP driver, as I've always done with ndiswrapper. Otherwise the driver should be on the original driver CD. [This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=863591) claims you should use the `rt2870.inf` from the `XP2K` driver. Make sure you have ndiswrapper properly configured (add ndiswrapper to `/etc/modules`, run `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` to have the driver kick in right away...). Otherwise you can try the `XP64` driver if the `XP2K` driver fails.

For blacklisting rt2500usb, you can try that, you can also add rt2870sta to `/etc/modules`.

That's the best I've found on the forums, seeing as I don't own that device myself. Basic steps for troubleshooting hardware in Linux (in my experience anyway) are:

- get the Vendor ID / Product ID (for USB devices) and Google it (and
  identify it in a system file or two if needed)
- grab libraries from the package manager that might be useful
- download a driver and point to it in a system file

Give it a try and post a comment.